# *BYVAL and *BYREF in CLLE

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to call a RPGLE procedure from a CLLE. Since the RPGLE procedure is existing, I cannot change it to extproc(*CL) type. I am currently in V7R1. I have used the below code. If i pass by *BYVAL the parameters are not getting passed. If i pass by *BYREF it is working. I have defined the parameters as CONST in RPGLE service. Please let me know if i have to do any additional changes to pass by value.

```
PGM                                                      

DCLPRCOPT  USRPRF(*OWNER) DFTACTGRP(*NO) ACTGRP(*NEW) +  
             BNDDIR(SAMSRV)                              

DCL        VAR(&CLNBR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(9)                
DCL        VAR(&USER) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)                
DCL        VAR(&IS_VLD) TYPE(*LGL)                       

CHGVAR     VAR(&CLNBR) VALUE('01112201T')                
CHGVAR     VAR(&USER)  VALUE('UUUUU ')                   

CALLPRC    PRC('IsValidClient') PARM((&CLNBR *BYREF) +
             (&USER *BYREF)) RTNVAL(&IS_VLD)             
ENDPGM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parms are coded as `CONST` in the RPGLE procedure, then you simply can not pass by value.

The parameter on the RPGLE side would need [`VALUE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/dvalue.htm#dvalue) keyword to be a pass by value parm.  [`CONST`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/dconst.htm#dconst) means passed by read-only reference.  When neither `CONST` nor `VALUE` is specified in RPGLE, then the parm is passed by reference.

You really should add the EXTPROC(*CL).  RPGLE and CL don't return 1-byte values quite the same way; Nor pass by value 1-byte variables the same way.  Prior to v6r1, you could code a temporary 2-byte variable to hold the returned value and then just copy the first byte to &IS_VLD.

Comment: I was always under the impression that CONST is equivalent to pass by value. So CONST is pass by reference but a read-only reference. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Correct.  Both `CONST` and `VALUE` allow you to pass literals...`callp myproc('Hi');`  But they use different mechanisms to do so.